# Trying to fill in a form using JavaScript, problems with loading DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fill out a multi-page form using JavaScript to automate it. The script I'm using is below.

```
// Page 1
document.getElementById("NextButton").click();

// Page 2
completion(document.getElementById("Receipt.1").setAttribute("aria-checked", true));
document.getElementById("NextButton").click();
```

The problem is that when run, document.getElementById() returns null and I'm sure it's because it hasn't loaded yet.

How can I fix this?

I tried wrapping `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {` around the code for the second page but it gave the error '...took too long to call the completion handler'.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: put your javascript below your html is one way. how is the page being loaded? dynamically with javascript ajax requests or a different way. Listening to the document ready event is a way to do it as well yes

Comment: @CotyEmbry The page is a webpage survey/form and the javascipt is being run using another program. How would I go about listening like you suggested?

Comment: Try `window.addEventListener("load", (event) => { ... });`, [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Comment: @rajniszp This still causes the error '...took too long to call the completion handler'

Answer (score 0):

An overcomplicated way to listen to the ready event without using the easy jquery way of `$(function() { /* your code here*/ })` would be something like

```
    (function(funcName, baseObj) {
    // The public function name defaults to window.docReady
    // but you can pass in your own object and own function name and those will be used
    // if you want to put them in a different namespace
    funcName = funcName || "docReady";
    baseObj = baseObj || window;
    var readyList = [], readyFired = false, readyEventHandlersInstalled = false;
    // call this when the document is ready
    // this function protects itself against being called more than once
    function ready() {
        if (!readyFired) {
            // this must be set to true before we start calling callbacks
            readyFired = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < readyList.length; i++) {
                // if a callback here happens to add new ready handlers,
                // the docReady() function will see that it already fired
                // and will schedule the callback to run right after
                // this event loop finishes so all handlers will still execute
                // in order and no new ones will be added to the readyList
                // while we are processing the list
                readyList[i].fn.call(window, readyList[i].ctx);
            }
            readyList = [];  // allow any closures held by these functions to free
        }
    }
    function readyStateChange() {
        if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) ready();
    }
    // This is the one public interface
    // docReady(fn, context);
    // the context argument is optional - if present, it will be passed
    // as an argument to the callback
    baseObj[funcName] = function(callback, context) {
        // if ready has already fired, then just schedule the callback
        // to fire asynchronously, but right away
        if (readyFired) {
            setTimeout(function() {callback(context);}, 1);
            return;
        } else {
            // add the function and context to the list
            readyList.push({fn: callback, ctx: context});
        }
        // if document already ready to go, schedule the ready function to run
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            setTimeout(ready, 1);
        } else if (!readyEventHandlersInstalled) {
            // otherwise if we don't have event handlers installed, install them
            if (document.addEventListener) {
                // first choice is DOMContentLoaded event
                document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready, false);
                // backup is window load event
                window.addEventListener("load", ready, false);
                
            } else {
                // must be IE
                document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", readyStateChange);
                window.attachEvent("onload", ready);
                
            }
            readyEventHandlersInstalled = true;
        }
    }
})('ready', window);
```

and you can call it like

```
window.ready(function() {                                                   //use the above code to run the below callback function after the document's ready event has fired
    /* run your document ready code */
});
```

It would be easier to include jquery and use their document ready api they've made though. Good luck

Edit: I finally found the original place I got some of this code before any modifications I made *I think*: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/1660185